# Android Baseadaper. getView gets called too few times

Tags: android, listview

I've seen many posts on issues similar to this problem but I still can't figure this out. I'm creating a simple `mediaplayer` using a custom `baseadapter` and a custom `listfragment`. Every `listview` holds a custom `textview` which starts an animation(horizontal scrolling) on the text when pressed.

`getCount()` in my `baseadapter` returns the size of the `baseadapter(size == 11)` correctly, but `getView()` is only called 10 times when the `adapter` is set.

At the moment, my screen comports nine list-items. When I press the top-item the horizontal scrolling starts and a song plays. If I then scroll upwards to see the last item, that item has also started the animation, which is not what I want.

Somebody has had a similar problem and can help me with this?

I have tried to update the views differently in `getView()` but the animation still occurs. To me, it seems that the problem is that `getView()` initially is only getting called `getCount() - 1` times.

```
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment {

    private Context mContext;
    private MyBaseAdapter mBaseAdapter;
    private MyListViewListener mListViewListener;
    private String mJsonStr;
    private IPlayer mPlayer;
    private int mCurrentTrack = -1;

    public interface MyListViewListener {
        void getListItemData(String str);
    }

    public static ListViewFragment newInstance() {
        return new ListViewFragment();
    }

    public ListViewFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        mPlayer = new package.name.Player(context);
        if(context instanceof MainActivity) {
            mListViewListener = (ListViewFragment.MyListViewListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement IEditTextListener");
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listviewfragment, container, false);
        mJsonStr = getArguments().getString("MainActivity");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Track> tracks = gson.fromJson(mJsonStr, new TypeToken<List<Track>>(){}.getType());

        mBaseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(mContext, tracks);
        setListAdapter(mBaseAdapter);

        return view; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        playPauseStop(position);
    }

    private ScrollTextView mStv;

    public void playPauseStop(int position) {

        int firstViewItemIndex = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int viewIndex = position - firstViewItemIndex;
        ScrollTextView stv = (ScrollTextView) getListView().getChildAt(viewIndex);

        if(mCurrentTrack == position && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            stv.pauseScroll();

        } else if(mCurrentTrack == position && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            // Start after pause
            mPlayer.play();
            stv.resumeScroll();
        } else if(mCurrentTrack != position && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            // Change track

            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer = new Player(mContext);
            String itemData = (String) mBaseAdapter.getItem(position);
            mPlayer.startPlayThread(itemData);
            mStv.stopScrolling();
            mStv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            mStv = stv;

            stv.startScroll();
            stv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            mCurrentTrack = position;
        }

        if(mCurrentTrack == -1) { // Initial. Start first track.
            mStv = stv;           // Keep track of view. Needed to stop horizontal scrolling when changing track if view is off screen.

            mCurrentTrack = position;

            String itemData = (String) mBaseAdapter.getItem(position);
            mPlayer.startPlayThread(itemData);
            stv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            stv.startScroll();

         }
    }
}


public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Typeface mTypeface;
    private List<Track> mTracks;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Track> tracks) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/specialfont.ttf");
        mTracks = tracks;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { // Returns the correct size
        return  mTracks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
         return mTracks.get(i).getLocation(); // track-URI
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    private  ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    static class ViewHolder {
        ScrollTextView mTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);

             mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
             mViewHolder.mTextView = (ScrollTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_text);
             mViewHolder.mTextView.setTypeface(mTypeface);
             mViewHolder.mTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
             mViewHolder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
             mViewHolder.mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             // store the holder with the view.
             view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else { // Avoid calling findViewById() when scrolling
             mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.mTextView.setText(mTracks.get(position).getArtist() + " : " + mTracks.get(position).getName());

        return view;
    } 

}
```

layout_listviewfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package.name.ScrollTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_text"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="72sp">
</package.name.ScrollTextView>
```

Comment: AFAIK `getView()` is only called for the items that are to be shown. Its not called for total size of your list. Other items will be created when you scroll the list and that row shows up.

Comment: Ok but nine items is initially shown but getView() is called ten times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If others having a similar problem I found a solution here:

https://graphics-geek.blogspot.se/2013/02/devbytes-listview-animations.html

Set your view like this: view.setHasTransientState(true)

This seems to prevent the view from being recycled when animating.